# Target version 16299 versus 17134 Pivot/Content presenter behavior differences

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I can't figure out what has changed between these two versions to display this behavior, but I would like to gather some insight on what might be happening from some different point of views. I have a Top level menu, containing a Sub level menu in which this display the actual content.

I have a MainPage with a pivot menu. The MainPages pivot contains within its ItemTemplate a Page named "Tab".

Each MainPage pivot selection has its own instance of "Tab"

Tab contains another Pivot menu. In the "Tab" pivot menu ItemTemplate, I have a ContentPresenter control thats bound to a collection item of type UserControl named "SubTabContent".

In 16299 each instance of the SubTabContent load event is fired when the sub tab is selected.
In 17134, all SubTabContent load events are fired without the sub tab being selected.

This is what i'm trying to control, but cannot find why this is happening. Is it the ContentPresenter? Or the pivot, or the architecture?

Steps to reproduce this. Create two Blank UWP Projects. Target one with 16299, and another with 17134.

Use the code/steps below for both apps. Set a break point in the load event of the SubTabContent user control, and you will see the difference between the two apps in how they load.

**I need the sublevel content to only load when i select the tab for it. I don't want it to load outside of that. I'm currently in 16299 which works fine, and would like to go up to 17134 for newer feature usage. but cannot since this load behavior.**

In the MainPage

```
<Page
    x:Class="_17134PivotExample.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:_17134PivotExample"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <StackPanel>
        <ScrollViewer BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="3">
            <Pivot ItemsSource="{x:Bind menuItems}">
                <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:MenuItem">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Header}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:MenuItem">
                        <local:Tab/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            </Pivot>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>



public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> menuItems { get; set; }
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            menuItems = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                menuItems.Add(new MenuItem
                {
                    Header = "Menu Tab + {i++}",
                    Content = new Tab()
                });

            }
        }
    }
```

Add one class in each app

```
public class MenuItem
    {
        public string Header { get; set; }
        public UserControl Content { get; set; }
    }
```

Add a page named "Tab"

```
<Page
    x:Class="_17134PivotExample.Tab"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:_17134PivotExample"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">



    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer  BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="3">
            <Pivot
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind menuItems}">
                <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:MenuItem">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Header}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:MenuItem">
                        <ScrollViewer>
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{x:Bind Content}" />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            </Pivot>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Page>



public sealed partial class Tab : Page
    {
        public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> menuItems { get; set; }
        public Tab()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            menuItems = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                menuItems.Add(new MenuItem
                {
                    Header = "Sub Menu Tab" + i++,
                    Content = new SubTabContent()
                });

            }
            this.Loaded += Tab_Loaded;
        }

        private void Tab_Loaded(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int blah = 1;
        }
    }
```

Add a UserControl named SubTabContent

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="_17134PivotExample.SubTabContent"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:_17134PivotExample"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="Black"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="New Page" />
        <TextBlock Text="New Page" />
        <TextBlock Text="New Page" />
        <TextBlock Text="New Page" />
        <TextBlock Text="New Page" />
        <TextBlock Text="New Page" />
        <TextBlock Text="New Page" />
        <TextBlock Text="New Page" />
        <TextBlock Text="New Page" />
        <TextBlock Text="New Page" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>



public sealed partial class SubTabContent : UserControl
    {
        public SubTabContent()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += SubTabContent_Loaded;
        }

        private void SubTabContent_Loaded(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int i = 0;
            Debug.WriteLine("Loaded" + i++);
        }
    }
```

Comment: With my tests, there's no problem. SubTabContent Loaded event always will be fired  when the sub tab is selected. What's your OS build version?

Comment: 16299 load event fires when sub tab is selected. 17134 loads all three tabs without selection.

Comment: What did you mean about '17134 loads all three tabs without selection.'? I've tested the 17134 project, there's no problem. When sub tab is selected, the loaded event will be fired. Please tell me your OS build version. If possible, please also record a video to show what happened on your side.

Comment: In 17134 all sub tabs load when a top level tab is selected. In 16299 only the sub tab you select loads. I want 16299's behavior in 17134. 
I'm 17134.

Comment: My project's target version is 17134. My OS build version is 18362. The behavior on my side is when a top tab is selected, only one sub tab's loaded event is fired.

Comment: Which Loaded event are you placing your breakpoint in? @XavierXie-MSFT

Comment: `SubTabContent_Loaded`

Comment: Hate to bother, but it's odd that i'm getting different results than you. This issue has been a thorn for a while, and I really want to get it figured out.

Comment: Just to add to this. It seems that the First Second, and last pivot content loads in the main layer, and sub layer. Very odd bug.. @XavierXie